# How can I render an HTML image from byte data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I render an HTML image from byte data loaded from a database?

I am retreiving data from database as a byte array. I need to convert that into png format.
Is this possible??

below shown is the byte array.

```
Byte[] imageArray = new byte[0];
MyData = (Byte[])dt.Tables[0].Rows[3]["img"];
```

Comment: How can someone upvote this question. It lacks information and is unclear what the expected end result should be.

Comment: I couldn't find the relationship between `imageArray` and `MyData` lol

Comment: If I understand well maybe you can use a library like ImageMaigck. I think with this you can construct an image to whatever format given a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the convert function. Refer the code below....

```
Byte[] imageArray = new byte[0];
MyData = (Byte[])dt.Tables[0].Rows[3]["img"];
if (imageArray!= null && imageArray.Length > 0)
{
   string img = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);
   pictureBox1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImagebyMemoryStream(byte[] imageByte)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
System.Drawing.Image newImage;
string strFileName = GetTempFolderName() + "yourfilename.gif";

if (byteArrayIn != null)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        newImage.Save(strFileName);
        img.Attributes.Add("src", strFileName);
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("No image data found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will Help You

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

return returnImage;
}